# Which graphics APIs texture formats are HDR texture formats?

Tags: texture, api

I understand that HDR files are images encoded with a higher precision in order to keep more details.
When loading such images in real-time rendering applications using common Graphics APIs (DirectX, OpenGL, Vulkan), which are the "HDR texture formats" that ensure details will be preserved?

Comment: Are you talking about the texel formats the GPU understands, or are you talking about the file formats that images are stored in before texture upload?

Comment: About the former

Comment: But connecting those with details about how the data is arranged in the image files would be interesting as well Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, using floating point textures will help preserve HDR values. They can be 16-bit or 32-bit floats for the color channels, usually. In OpenGL you could choose the type to be `GL_FLOAT` for 32-bits per channel or `GL_HALF_FLOAT` for 16-bits per channel. In my experience, for image processing, 16-bits is usually enough and is half as much data.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider these alternatives for reducing bandwidth in comparison to R16G16B16A16.

DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_UF16 is block compressed fp16 (half) RGB.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/bc6h-format

DXGI_FORMAT_R11G11B10 unsigned small float

> https://bartwronski.com/2017/04/02/small-float-formats-r11g11b10f-precision/

Common image file formats for HDR are exrs or dds. They're pretty trivially encoded as 32-bit or 16-bit per channel floats.

Comment: Thanks for the complementary info and for the link to an interesting blog post